# Ebay Finding API: Not getting same number of result via API call as that of manual search using the same filters in ebay site

Tags: javascript, arrays, ebay-api

I am using `finding API` of `e-bay` to get the completed list of items.

I am using their sample code to call the API. But when I search with the keyword and same filter then I'm getting the subset of result but I'm not getting completed list of items. It only gave some top results.

This is my filters:

```
var filterarray = [
  {"name":"FreeShippingOnly", 
   "value":"true", 
   "paramName":"", 
   "paramValue":""},
   {"name": "Condition",
    "value": "Used",
    "paramName":"", 
    "paramValue":""},
   {"name": "SoldItemsOnly",
     "value": "true",
    "paramName":"", 
    "paramValue":""},
  ];
```

Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters

```
function  buildURLArray() {
   // Iterate through each filter in the array
  for(var i=0; i<filterarray.length; i++) {
    //Index each item filter in filterarray
    var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
    // Iterate through each parameter in each item filter
for(var index in itemfilter) {
  // Check to see if the paramter has a value (some don't)
  if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
    if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
      for(var r=0; r<itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
      var value = itemfilter[index][r];
      urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value ;
      }
    } 
    else {
      urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + itemfilter[index];
    }
  }
}
}

 }  // End buildURLArray() function


        // Execute the function to build the URL filter

buildURLArray(filterarray);
```

This is my url:

```
var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=my_app_id";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&keywords=%22iphone+5%22";
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=25";
    url += "&sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest";
    url += urlfilter;
```

I have thoroughly checked the FindindAPI documentation and each filter parameter and their corresponding value.
Is it some functionality of `finding API` that restricted to get the completed list or I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Because you specified  url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=25";
it means only top 25 results will come. Try to change the  number in entriesPerPage. You will definetly find the whatever result you want.